# openMP for don't improve overal perfomance

Tags: c#, c++, openmp

I am using a c++ dll in order to do some computational intensive processing- my c++ uses threads - and use this dll in my c# application.

I used MS visual studio profiler to identify the parts of code which consumes most time.

and used openMP for improving the performance through distributing the work load among a Intel i7 8 core processor running @2.9GHz.

the following code for example consumes to much time of the cpu

```
for (short j = 0; j < 4096; j++)
    histsum[j] = hist_tmp[row][col][0][j] + hist_tmp[row][col][1][j] + hist_tmp[row][col][2][j] + hist_tmp[row][col][3][j];
```

so I modified it to

```
#pragma omp parallel for
                for (short j = 0; j < 4096; j++)
                    histsum[j] = hist_tmp[row][col][0][j] + hist_tmp[row][col][1][j] + hist_tmp[row][col][2][j] + hist_tmp[row][col][3][j];
```

i noticed that the 8 cores are 100% loaded , but the overall performance is not improved.

What could be the problem? and how could I overcome it?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: generally you don't reduce cpu time by using more threads. It is rather more cpu time. You want to measure wall clock time not cpu time

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I understand that I am not reducing CPU time, I mention that cpu is 100% loaded to indicate that openMP is parallelizing my code, and utilization of cpu is improved which is expected, but what is strange is that the overall performance which is measured by wall clock is degraded and not improved

Comment: i was just pointing you to something that potentially is a misunderstanding. It might be just wording. You write "consumes to much time of the cpu ... so i modified it to ...". Anyhow, there is too little information in the question to know why there is no speed up. If you want help with code you should include a [mcve]. Quesitons about performance typically require even more information, what times did you measure? How did you measure? What compiler? What compiler flags? etc...

Comment: Because the workload is very small, the overheads kill the speed improvement. For a modern processor adding 4 vectors of size 4096  is a very small workload and not worth parallelizing..

Comment: @Laci is this true even if this calculation is repeated to several threads?
is there a guide line when openMP will be useful ? dose the same rule apply for using GPU with cuda ?

Comment: I do not understand your first question. This calculation takes less than a millisecond (even microseconds) , you should parallelize bigger part of your program.  Since we do not know the structure of your program we cannot give you advice about it.

Comment: My suggestion is to Edit your post and provide a minimal reproducible example (as already suggested by @mjwills)  which runs for at least hundreds of milliseconds. After that we can tell you which parts of your code should be parallelized and what to use (OpenMP, GPU, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Neither C++, nor multi threading, automatically improve performance. Both need to be applied where appropriate to get any benefit.

Using multi threading have some overhead to delegate work and synchronize the the results. If each task is small the overhead will be larger than any possible gain. Adding four numbers together is absolutely to small for this to be useful. You need to apply multi-threading to much larger chunks of data for it to be useful.

I would also not expect any huge gains by using c++ for code like this. The C++ compiler is in general better at optimizing code, but for simple code like this even the c# compiler should do a decent job. You might see some small improvement by moving the indexing, `hist_tmp[row][col]`, outside the loop. This indexing might be optimized away already, but it might be worth a try.

This kind of code should however benefit from SIMD. Some c++ compilers have options for auto-vectorization. To get the best performance from c# there is [intrinstics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/) in .net core.

A very important point is to **measure** performance using the appropriate tools for the platform. In c# this would be a [stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0), but tools like [benchmark.net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) are recommended since they handle things like compilation overhead. A good profiler is also very useful.

I would also suggest looking for any algorithmic improvements, caching opportunities or other unnecessary or repeated work before going to multi threading and c++. The former can often have a far larger effect on performance.

Comment: btw it is completely unclear what OPs code is adding, it could be some custom type with an expensive `operator+`. Though you are probably right